# Can someone help me knowing if any prerequisite is require for VC++ binary built using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

Background details: We had an binary built using old visual studio that required Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable as prerequisites. Our need is to remove this dependency.
So when we rebuild the VC++ binary using Visual Studio 2015 it avoids the dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable and works fine on PC not having that prerequisites.

I want to ensure that it will work on all latest OS irrespective if any version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is installed.

Comment: You need to do a clean build which recompiles all the source files.  The dependency to 2005 are in the obj files that are not getting recompiled.

Comment: You'll now have a dependency on the VS2015 runtime.  It is much easier to deploy, a simple local copy of the runtime dlls gets the job done.  It is technically possible to link the runtime support library into the final executable (/MT option), but that generally only works for simple programs that don't use libraries.  Judging from the [c#] tag on the question, /MT tends to work well for [DllImport] libraries that were built to just a single deployable .dll